# Gradle task 'wrapper' not found in project ':subproject'

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, intellij-idea

I have root gradle project which needs to have a small Spring Boot subproject. This subproject will be deployed in the same pod as root project, so it needs to be built whenever root project is built. I tried by creating the following structure:

```
subproject/
├─ src/...
├─ build.gradle
settings.gradle
```

with the following contents:

**settings.gradle**:

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}

rootProject.name = 'root'


include 'subproject'
```

**build.gradle**:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.0'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.demo'
version = '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

But when I refresh the project from within the IDEA, it shows `Task 'wrapper' not found in project ':subproject'`. What did  miss? This subproject cannot exist by itself and shouldn't have a 'wrapper', it should be build by the root project.

```bash
$ ./gradlew -q projects
Root project 'root'
+--- Project ':subproject'
```

**Gradle version: 6.8.3, Java version: 11**

Answer (score 11):

The problem actually does not exist. Everything is correct, except that IDEA added subproject as separate gradle project (I guess). So when I hit refresh, it could not be performed because IDEA was trying to find wrapper in the subproject. Simply saying, if you have such problem, check how many projects you have in your IDEA's Gradle view. In my case, there was two - root and subproject, the latter is unneeded.

Comment: On the gradle tab in IDEA, right click on the project and click on "- Unlink Gradle Project"

Comment: For anyone still experiencing this issue and cannot find the solution in IntelliJ as I just had this issue. When you create a Gradle Subproject and delete the gradle wrapper file or receive this error, just close IntelliJ and delete the .idea folder inside the parent project file and reopen IntelliJ.